# What's the difference between "either" and "at the same time"?

Tags: difference

> I can't carry a heavy bag and a heavy heart, **either**.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Can I say this instead?

> I can't carry a heavy bag and a heavy heart **at the same time**.

Comment: The either in your sentence refers to some previous context. For example: I don't like cheese. And I don't like milk, either.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the word ***either***. It doesn't mean "at the same time". It's used to indicate a similarity or link with a statement just made, such as *I can't carry a heavy bag. I can't carry a heavy heart, either.* (i can't do the first thing, NOR can I do the second thing).

Comment: Another interpretation of your first sentence, depending on context, is “I can’t carry both of those heavy things any more than you can.” **So much** depends on context and what meaning the speaker intends.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is grammatical. But it means something completely different from your second sentence.

In the coordinate structure *either ... or*, "either" means "one or the other". It usually  implies "but not both", though this is partly a matter of context.

So

> I can carry either a heavy bag or a heavy heart.

is what I think you mean to say.

When *either* is in the scope of a negative, it usually means "not one and not the other", the same as "neither", so

> I can't carry either a heavy bag or a heavy heart

is the same as

> I can carry neither a heavy bag nor a heavy heart

and both mean that I can't carry a heavy bag *and* I can't carry a heavy heart, which is not what you intend, I think.

When *either* is used as you have used it, as a free adverb, it means "just like some (negative) thing that has previously been said", as the comments have explained.

Comment: While I grant you that "either" has this definition, the structure of the OP's original sentence (which I will assume is correct and lifted out of context) strongly implies that it's being used for agreement in a negative sentence, filling the role of "too" or "also". I see that you have a small comment about it, but it might be worth asking the OP to clarify so you can structure your answer specifically to the usage. Otherwise someone coming to this answer for a sentence pair like "I can't X" "I can't X either" may be quite confused.

Answer (score 3):

***Either*** can indicate a similarity or link with a (negated) statement just made. So with OP's existing phrasing, the word ***either*** can only refer back to some previous statement not supplied above. For example...

> A: *"I can't carry a heavy bag and a heavy heart"*
> B: *"I can't carry a heavy bag and a heavy heart, either"*
> (B's statement is "like" A's)

---

For the meaning OP *wants* to convey, it's just...

> 1: *I can't carry a heavy bag **and** a heavy heart*

...where my bold type isn't to call your attention to the word ***and*** - it's to indicate that the speaker is placing ***heavy stress*** on that word. The effect of this is to strongly imply...

> 2: *[At any given point in time...]
>
> I can carry **either** a heavy bag **or** a heavy heart
>
> [...but **I can't carry both at once**]*

---

Note that there's also...

> 3: *I can't carry a heavy bag **or** a heavy heart*

...again, with speaker (*probably* but not *necessarily,* in this case) placing heavy stress on the bolded word. The effect of ***this*** version is to strongly imply...

> 4: *I can carry **neither** a heavy bag **nor** a heavy heart*

Maybe I can carry light things like feathers, but I can't carry ***either*** of those heavy things.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

> I don't like chocolate, or peppermint, either.

You don't like chocolate.

You don't like peppermint.

You like neither.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I like what you're going for with that allegorical analogy. I don't think *either* sentence is erroneous, but *at the same time* they don't mean the same thing.

If you mean you are able to carry a heavy bag so long as your heart is light, the latter is fine.

If you mean that you're incapable of carrying either then the former works, but a couple of extra words could help with clarifying.

"I can't carry a heavy bag, certainly not with the burden of a heavy heart."